# error 404: while deploying slim framework rest API on plesk shared hosting

Tags: slim

I need help, while deploying slim framework on plesk shared hosting below mentioned issue is coming up.
actually it is working fine at local wamp server.

**404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

**here is my code.**

**index.php:**

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');

$config = ['settings' => [
    'addContentLengthHeader' => true,
    'displayErrorDetails' => true
]];

$app = new \Slim\App($config);
require '../src/routes/hostUser.php';
require '../src/routes/user.php';
$app->run();
```

**hostUser.php:**

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Slim\Http\Message;
include_once 'Database.php';
var_dump($app);

$app->get('/loadprofile', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $user_email = $_GET['emailid'];
    $userid =  $_GET['usertypeid'];

    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
    try {
        $stmt =  $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE userid='".$userid."' AND email='".$user_email."'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return json_encode($res);

        $db = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }

});
```

The control reached till var_dump($app) but it is not executing **loadprofile** service.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QslZ.png)

Comment: `/public` should not be part of the url. Ensure that you set the correct apache documentRoot to the public/ directory. Please add your `.htaccess` file to the question.